# Simple Node.js program uses UDP packets and requires ports to be forwarded on both client and server

Tags: node.js, sockets, portforwarding

What would be the best way of solving this? I have read about UDP hole punching and about some kind of auto port forwarding but I do not understand the benefits of one method over the other.